# How to Reference Image Path from SQL Database in Asp.Net for jQuery SlideShow

Tags: jquery, html, sql, asp.net, image

I have a website which contains an image bar of three images the in header section like so:

[image: Image Bar]

Currently, I've written the following jQuery to `fadeIn` & `fadeOut` at least the first image on a 3 second timer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        setTimeout(function (){
            $('#Image1').fadeOut('slow');                                     
        }, 3000);            

    });

    var fadeBack = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#Image1').fadeIn('slow');
        }, 6000);
    };

    fadeBack();        
</script>
```

What I'm having difficulty figuring out is how I can actually make a slideshow out the rest of the images in the Images folder. Thus I built in a DB with the structure as such:

[image: Photos Table Structure]

And here's the data view of the paths in the table:

[image: Data View of Image Paths]

Lastly, here's my `Web.config` file's `<connectionStrings>` info:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DetailPhotosEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.DetailPhotos.csdl|res://*/App_Code.DetailPhotos.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.DetailPhotos.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DetailPhotos;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I was told I would have change my `<connnectionStrings>` following another site's info. How do I call the image URLs into the header image placeholders from my DB, and set the behavior up as a slideshow with `fadeIn` & `fadeOut` on the images? Would I be, in effect, fading the image paths from the `DetailPhotos` DB? This is my most ambitious work yet, and I'm lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to store your image paths in a database? The only reason I would consider doing that is if you intend to introduce some way of dynamically updating the images at some point.

If you are happy to just update the images in the slideshow by updating your script manually, i'd consider adapting the following, taken from [this page.](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/create-simple-image-slide-show-using.html) (Untested)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Slide Show with jQuery</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imgs = [
        'images/emo.jpg',
        'images/icon068.gif',
        'images/icon260.jpg'];
        var cnt = imgs.length;

        $(function() {
            setInterval(Slider, 3000);
        });

        function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
           $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn("slow");
        });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="imageSlide" alt="" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

this bit allows you to add as many images as you want:

```
var imgs = [
'images/emo.jpg',
'images/icon068.gif',
'images/icon260.jpg'];
```

Comment: Thank you, but does this implement for just one instance of an Image placeholder, or does it span across all 3 of the image placeholders I have set up... i.e., `#Image1`, `#Image2`, and `#Image3`?

Comment: I see that it works for one... just got back around to working on this project. I'll just write up another 2 functions for the other boxes, and tuck the code away in a file somewhere in the solution to save space in the MasterPage. Thanks!